# javascript convert $ string to number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of form fields that have values like $1.00, $1654.31 and i would like to convert them to a numerical string only so i can calculate the values.

Im looping over each one, but keep getting NaN when i log to the console.

```
$("input.costs").each(function( index) {
    console.log( $(this).val()  + parseFloat( $(this).val() )    );
});
```

each time it returns NaN, im wondering whether there is an easy way to make a dollar value string convert to a numerical value only for calculating ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You should remove the `$`, `$` is not a number.

Comment: @Musa: "I have a set of form fields that have values like $1.00, $1654.31"

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$("input.costs").each(function( index) {
    console.log( $(this).val()  + parseFloat( $(this).val().replace('$','') )    );
});
```

Comment: Instead of `$(this).val()` you can use `this.value`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numberWithoutDollar = numberWithDollar.replace(/^\$/, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove everything but numbers, `.`, `-` and `+`.

```
$("input.costs").each(function( index) {
    console.log( $(this).val()  + parseFloat( $(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.\+-]/g, "") )    );
});
```

Examples:

```
parseFloat("-1.00".replace(/[^\d\.\+-]/g, ""))
// -1

parseFloat("+1654.31 ".replace(/[^\d\.\+-]/g, ""))
// 1654.31
```

Answer (score 0):

just skip the dollar sign.

```
parseFloat($(this).val().substr(1))
```